# Error when convert byte array to BitmapImage in UWP

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, bitmapimage

I want to get a BitmapImage when capture view's screenshot. So I start to get byte array data first, then convert to BitmapImage.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTarget.RenderAsync(swapChainPanel);    
IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderTarget.GetPixelsAsync();

await GetBitmapAsync(pixelBuffer.ToArray());
...
public static async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapAsync(byte[] data)
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            try
            {
                using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    using (var writer = new DataWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteBytes(data);
                        await writer.StoreAsync();
                        await writer.FlushAsync();
                        writer.DetachStream();
                    }

                    stream.Seek(0);
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream); // throw Exception
                }

                return bitmapImage;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

But it give error :

> The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: Which line throw this error within above code ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT That's `await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error when convert byte array to BitmapImage in UWP

The problem is you have not specific `BitmapEncoder` for `BitmapImage` when convertering. In general, we often use the following code to get `BitmapImage` from bytes.

```
_backAction = new Action<byte[]>(async (bytes) =>
{
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();     
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
        (uint)48,
        (uint)32,
        DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        bytes);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);
});
```